# Is there an app for the iPhone 4 that tells the pitch of a note through an audio input?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, applications, audio

Does anyone know of an app for the iPhone that can analyze sounds and tell us what pitch the sound is?

For example, if i had that app running and i go to the piano and play some notes, it should be able to tell me what notes they are.

Comment: An app for what platform? iPhone, Macintosh, Windows? Do you have an audio interface and a microphone to use with your computing platform?

Comment: @Wheat i-phone 4

Comment: Why didn't you say so in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garageband can do this. Open a new (or existing) project and add a new "real" track with no effects. On the bottom edge of the window you´ll see a LCD-like window which usually displays the current time or measure in the track; depending on which version of Garageband you´re using, you can now either use the up-/down-arrows to switch to the tuner (tuning fork symbol) or click on the tuning fork symbol directly to select the tuner. Every sound that is picked up by your Mac´s microphone will now be displayed as note (with off-pitch)

Comment: Are you aware if there is a "free" app that evaluates the pitch of a *sound*?

Answer (score 1):

Identifying a single pitch is one thing. Any "tuner" or "guitar tuner" app can do that, as well as any [dedicated hardware tuner](http://www.guitarcenter.com/Accessories,New-Gear.gc?src=tuner).

However, analyzing the notes in a *chord*, or transcribing a musical passage from an audio source *in real time*, is not something that any existing program can do on any computer platform.

There is a Windows and Macintosh program for electronic music composition and audio recording and editing called [Melodyne](http://www.celemony.com/cms/index.php?id=383) that can analyze the individual notes in a chord from something that's been recorded, and then let you edit those notes independently.